# Finding whether the given set is a subspace of $\mathbb{ R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $\{(x,y):\sin^2x+\sin^2y=0\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{ R}^2$?

Is $\{(x,y):\sin^2x+\cos^2y=1\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{ R}^2$?

My attempt: subspaces of $\mathbb{ R}^2$ are precisely ${0}$, $\mathbb{ R}^2$ and the lines passing through origin.Since the above sets don't constitute any of these subspaces, they are  not subspaces.Is my attempt correct

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good enough, but the statement that your set is equal to none of those sets without any proof is a bit too brief. *Why* is it not any of those subspaces? Once you've given a proof of that, your answer is good to go.

That being said, I would personally have preferred your answer had it instead had the approach of how your set breaks the axioms of vector spaces, rather than the exhaustive listing of the subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ and showing that your set is none of them. It is how these problems are usually solved, and basically what you will have to do anyway.

Comment: IMHO the OP's solution shows imagination and intelligence and is much better than grinding through routine procedures.  I would definitely give it full marks if it were up to me.  (But of course the routine procedure needs to be known as well.)

Comment: @David I see your point and I agree that it is cool to see students go off the beaten track. However, just stating that it is equal to none of the subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ without any calculations or drawings to back it up just isn't enough IMO. If this were on a test that I was correcting, then the answer as written by OP shows no evidence that they actually know how to solve this, only that they guessed correctly on a yes-no question, and that they know a general fact about $\Bbb R^2$ as vector space that seems relevant. I'm not asking for much more, but as it stands it's too brief.

Comment: I am sorry, but wont the first set be a subspace?

Comment: @jnyan No. $(0,\pi)$ is in that space, but not $\frac12(0,\pi)$. This is why I would personally have preferred a proof using the axioms: it's a lot shorter and there is less room for doubt whether the problem is actually understood and solved.